# How to get the generic type T as object declared in a function C#

Tags: c#

```
    public static List<T> GetColumnValuesByHeader<T>(string docName)
    {
      //  How can i get T as Customer or Employee in here?    
    }

List<Customer> customers = GetColumnValuesByHeader<Customer>("Customers.dat")
List<Employee> employees= GetColumnValuesByHeader<Employee>("Employees.dat")
```

Comment: If you find yourself needing to treat different `T` s differently, that's a sign that the method perhaps shouldn't be generic in `T` in the first place.

Comment: Eek - if we need to have type specific code in our generic then why do we need generics?

Comment: *@Webbies:* Do you want to get the `System.Type` for `T` (if so, see e.g. Jon Skeet's answer), or rather an actual object of type `Employee`/`Customer` (then see e.g. Mark H's answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon Skeet said you can use typeof to get the type of T.  You can also use the [Activator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) to create an instance of that class.

```
Type theType = typeof(T);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
```

Comment: If you're not going to pass in any parameters, then add a constraint and just call `new T()`.

Comment: Ya thanks Jon and Fermin. I wanted to SetValue of a Property of Type T.It works.

Answer (score 4):

Use `typeof(T)`:

```
public static List<T> GetColumnValuesByHeader<T>(string docName)
{
    // Will print Customer or Employee appropriately
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}
```

Now what exactly you do with that afterwards is up to you...

If you actually need to handle the cases differently, then I'd be tempted to write separate methods to start with. Generics are really designed for algorithms which behave the same way for any type. There are exceptions to every rule, of course - such as optimizations in `Enumerable.Count<T>`... and if you're fetching properties by reflection, for example, then that's a reasonable use of `typeof(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create many `T` to populate your list, the simplest way is to use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>();`. You wanna add the `where T : new()` constraint to your method though, to make this easy. It'll assume Customer and Employee each have a default constructor - if that isn't the case, you can still use `CreateInstance()`, but you'll need to grab the correct arguments to pass by getting the `ConstructorInfo` for each type.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of T using typeof..

```
Type t = typeof(T);
if (t == typeof(Employee))
{
    //Do something here ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (type of T Is Customer) {
 //Perform action for customer
} else

if (type of T Is Employee) {
 //Perform action for Employee
}
```

Comment: Yes, its a VB code sorry. in C# should be typeof(T) == Customer, peace